# Lost files while tried to move files using python shutil.move

Tags: python, shutil

I had 120 files in my source folder which I need to move to a new directory (destination). The destination is `made` in the function I wrote, based on the `string` in the filename. For example, here is the function I used.

```
path   ='/path/to/source'
dropbox='/path/to/dropbox'
files = = [os.path.join(path,i).split('/')[-1] for i in os.listdir(path) if i.startswith("SSE")]
sam_lis      =list()
for sam in files:
    sam_list =sam.split('_')[5]
    sam_lis.append(sam_list)
    sam_lis  =pd.unique(sam_lis).tolist()

# Using the above list
ID  = sam_lis

def filemover(ID,files,dropbox):
    """
    Function to move files from the common place to the destination folder
    """
    for samples in ID:
        for fs in files:
            if samples in fs:
                desination = dropbox  + "/"+ samples + "/raw/"
                if not os.path.isdir(desination):
                    os.makedirs(desination)
        for rawfiles in fnmatch.filter(files, pat="*"):
            if samples in rawfiles:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(path,rawfiles), 
                            os.path.join(desination,rawfiles))
```

In the function, I am creating the destination folders, based on the ID's derived from the files list. When I tried to run this for the first time it threw me `FILE NOT exists error`. 
However, later when I checked the source all files starting with `SSE` were missing. In the beginning, the files were there. I want some insights here;

1. Whether or not `os.shutil.move` moves the files to somewhere like a temp folder instead of destination folder?
2. whether or not the `os.shutil.move` deletes the files from the source in any circumstance?
3. Is there any way I can test my script to find the potential reasons for missing files?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated?

Comment: I'd replace `if not os.path.isdir(desination):` with `if not os.path.exists()` (or possibly `and` the two together). Or, as I prefer to do in python 3, `os.makedirs('path', exist_ok=True)`

Comment: All these are done in python3. Ok, thanks for suggestions. That wouldn't solve the issue here. My question is: Whether or not is there a potential that original files from source directory would be missing due to usage of `shutil.move`. IF yes, what could be that? How can I avoid the same happening in the future?

Comment: Yes, there is, `move` removes the files after copying them over (or uses `os.rename` which does the same thing modifying only the filesystem records). This is for the "They're not there anymore" part. As per the "where are they", check if you accidentally set a `destination` which is not what you're expecting. From what I can understand from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), `move` should only remove the files after a successful copy, so it is possible your files are just *somewhere* on your drive.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. I so checked all possible directories within my system to find them but could not recover. Hence, my second concern is whether or not `shutil.move` would move these files to any temporary folders? or in any invisible directory?

Comment: Not any temp folder, no. Invisible, as hidden, would be possible on linux if your destination folder would accidentally start with a `.`, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is late but people don't understand the op's question. If you move a file into a non-existing folder, the file seems to become a compressed binary and get lost forever. It has happened to me twice, once in git bash and the other time using shutil.move in Python. I remember the python happens when your shutil.move destination points to a folder instead of to a copy of the full file path.

For example, if you run the code below, a similar situation to what the op described will happen:

```
src_folder = r'C:/Users/name'
dst_folder = r'C:/Users/name/data_images'
file_names = glob.glob(r'C:/Users/name/*.jpg')

for file in file_names:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    shutil.move(os.path.join(src_folder, file_name), dst_folder)
```

Note that dst_folder is just a folder. It should be dst_folder + file_name. This will cause what the Op described in his question. I find something similar on the link here with a more detailed explanation of what went wrong: [File moving mistake with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554145/file-moving-mistake-with-python)

Comment: Joe, I only proved that shutil.move can cause files to get lost forever. I don't have the OP's system file setup to provide better help. For others, when moving files, first note out the expected destination path, then run your code replacing `shutil.move` with `print`. If the output is expected, then you can move the files.

Comment: I could be wrong, but my interpretation of what's happening above is that you're not ending the destination with a '/' so it interprets it as a file and just keeps copying each of the files to a file named `C:/Users/name/data_images`. I'd guess if you renamed it to have a `.jpg` extension again it would open and be the last image that was copied.

Answer (score 0):

shutil.move does not delete your files, if for any reason your files failed to move to a given location, check the directory where your code is stored, for a '+' folder your files are most likely stored there.